# C++ exceptions (usage hints)

Tags: c++, exception

I have two questions/reflections/doubts about C++ exceptions:

1. IMO when we think about using exceptions in code we have to make unambiguous decision - always use exceptions or not use them at all. This clarifies how an application will handle errors and code will be easier to read. I also always assume, that something may throw exception and I put try/catch block almost everywhere. Are my "rules" reasonable?
2. Are all exceptions thrown by STL classes and algorithms derived from `std::exception`? My exception classes always derives from standard class (`runtime_error`, `logic_error` etc.). I wonder if I can safely replace `catch (...)` with `catch(const std::exception& object)`, because the second one always provides some information about the exception's cause.

Comment: It's good to assume that everything will throw an exception.  But only `catch` if you need to cleanup or "handle" an exception.  Don't catch random exceptions.

Comment: What is the purpose of those try/catch blocks? If you cannot handle the exception, of course you shouldn't catch it. Sounds like you're catching them for no reason. Also, [check out this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Andrei-Alexandrescu-Systematic-Error-Handling-in-C). And yes, all exception classes should inherit from `std::exception`. You usually should have a `catch (...)` at the bottom of main just for completeness. But regardless, this is not constructive because it does not have a definite answer.

Comment: @GManNickG Care to post that as an answer so I can upvote?

Comment: @JohnKugelman: Might be a bit weird to say the question shouldn't be answered on the site then answer it. :) A comment is good enough for me, thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

For the first part this is a worth while read about exceptions in c++, in relation in when you should throw them, when you should catch them, why they are useful, and a lot of other helpful stuff.
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/exceptions.html

As for the second part as far as I know if you are catching exceptions from the stl you should be safe to use (const std::exception& object)

Answer (score 0):

1. I know what you mean.  Steve mcConnell wrote in Code Complete that exceptions should only be used in *Exceptional* circumstances I.e. if you really expect something to be there, like hard drive space, or a database connection. He goes on to say that exceptions *Should not* be used for control flow. This is where error codes come into play. I'd use both where appropriate.
2. There should be a way to determine the base type of the exceptions in the std template library. In my experience everything derives from std::exception

Comment: I agree with you on point 1 somewhat.  Because exceptions are expensive.  Don't throw exceptions when a return value would be more appropriate.  You can write a macro to wrap up the return value checks to make it concise and easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, yes, all exceptions thrown in the standard library derive from `std::exception`.

Your first question is harder to give a concrete answer to. In any non-trivial program, it is very hard to avoid exceptions completely. I think Herb Sutter goes through it quite nicely [here](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/020.htm).

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of those try/catch blocks? If you cannot handle the exception, of course you shouldn't catch it. Sounds like you're catching them for no reason.

Also, check out this video: [C++ and Beyond 2012: Andrei Alexandrescu - Systematic Error Handling in C++](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Andrei-Alexandrescu-Systematic-Error-Handling-in-C).

And yes, all exception classes should inherit from std::exception. You usually should have a catch (...) at the bottom of main just for completeness.